# Filtro para form en Django 1.9

Tags: django, django-forms

Tengo un proyecto donde creo personas y productos, y en un momento dado tengo una pantalla donde debo buscar los productos que tiene una persona de esta forma:

[image: pantalla1]

Al dar clic a "move" mando el id de esa fila (pertenece a una clase RecursoAsignado) a una página donde le debo asignar otra persona al producto así:

[image: pantalla2]

La acción de mover el objeto a un  nuevo dueño me funciona correctamente pero quiero saber cómo poner un filtro al segundo form para que me excluya el anterior dueño del objeto.

### Estoy usando views como funciones:

models.py

```
class Persona(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
class Recurso(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
class RecursoAsignado(models.Model):
    person_warehouse = models.ForeignKey(Persona)
    resource_warehouse = models.ForeignKey(Recurso)
```

forms.py

```
El form por el que pregunto:
class BuscarMoverForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BuscarMoverForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    person = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=True, queryset=Person.objects.all())
```

views.py

```
El view por el que pregunto:
def mover(request, idAsignado=None):
    assignment = None
    try:
        assignment = RecursoAsignado.objects.get(id=idAsignado)
    except Exception as e:
        pass
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BuscarMoverForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Actual Registro
            personId = assignment.person_warehouse.id
            assignment.assigned = False
            assignment.save()
            # Nuevo Registro
            fecha_hora_actual = datetime.now()
            new_person = form.cleaned_data['person']
            new_assignment = ResourcesAssignment(
                person_warehouse=new_person,
                resource_warehouse=assignment.resource_warehouse,
                date_assignment=fecha_hora_actual,
                assigned=True,
            )
            new_assignment.save()
            return redirect("resourcestock:search_assignment", personId)
    else:
        form = BuscarMoverForm()

    template = loader.get_template('resourcestock/move_assignment.html')
    context = {
         'form': form,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Entonces mi pregunta es... ¿cómo hago para modificar el form de manera que capture o conozca ese dato pasado por url (el id de RecursoAsignado) y pueda filtrar a todas las personas menos el actual dueño del producto (la persona de ese RecursoAsignado)?

Comment: ¿Pusiste el código de la view que genera la segunda página? Porque ahí podrías usar un filtro `.exclude()`, mira [la documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-all-objects). Actualiza tu pregunta para que sea más fácil crear la respuesta.

Comment: ese es el que muestro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

como menciono @toledano agrega el .exclude, pero primero en tu view debes pasar el id,

```
else:
    form = BuscarMoverForm(id=idAsignado)
```

y en tu forms

```
class BuscarMoverForm(forms.Form):
    person = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=True, queryset=None)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.id_asignado = kwargs.pop('id')
        super(BuscarMoverForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.person.queryset = Person.objects.all().exclude(id=self.id_asignado)
```

avisame si te funciono

Comment: muchas gracias :D sólo tuve que hacer una consulta antes porque el id era de la tabla intermedia, pero me ha funcionado perfectamente.